# Nifi rest command to create new processor group from nifi-registry?

Tags: rest, apache-nifi, developer-tools, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to create a new Processor Group from the latest version of one of the Processor Groups in my Nifi-Registry. However, I want to do this via REST API, but I am not able to find the rest command that works.

As suggested online in one of the forums, I tried using chrome developer tools to check the REST calls, but when I use developer tools, the drag and drop feature does not work in the UI! I don't know what am I doing wrong in the developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no reason why dev tools interferes with the application. Here is the request shown in dev tools when creating a PG and selecting to import from registry...

[image]

Here is the content of the request, it should be the same as creating a regular PG, except the version control information is specified:

[image]

Comment: The device was set as mobile, which I had to turn off. That did it.